# Finding a particular field of particular documents (specified by id) and updating them

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, postman, mern

First of all, I just wanna say that I'm just a beginner in MERN technology.
So, I am working on a game application. In this application, my users will have a list of players and they will select 11 players from that list and create their teams. Now, after the game ends, I will update the points of each player. Now, multiple users can have same player in their teams. So, I want every player in every user's team to have same points as well. For example, if there is a player named 'x' and multiple users have player 'x' in their teams and player 'x' has earned 20 points. So, I want all the player 'x' instances in every user's team to have 20 points each. Plus, I want to increment those 20 points to the total points of that user's team's total points. So, how can I implement this using nodejs. Just to furthur add-on a bit, my mongo schema is designed in such a way that each document (representing each user's team) have an array in which that user's selected players are stored. Snippet is provided below.

```
const MyTeam_Schema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
      team: [
          {
            name: { type: String },
            role: { type: String },
            team: { type: String },
            points: { type: Number, default: 0 },
            _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            isCaptain: {
              type: Boolean,
              default: false
            }
          }
      ],
      tournmentid: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Tournment'
      },
      userid: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      totalPoints: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      }
    }
)
```

I want make this happen on one click. Like, I would like to just enter _id of that player and points and hit enter (either through postman or a frontend page) and want the points and total points to get updated for that particular player. But that's my thinking. Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.
Note: Also, you would see that there is 'isCaptain' field. Actually, I want the captain (a player who is also a captain selected by the user) to earn double the points. Like if player 'x' originally got 20 points but if he was the captain, I want him to get 40 points but that i know that i just need to do *=2 to make that happen. But for the rest, my code isn't working.
If anyone want, I can post the code snippet as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: Then you have to lookup all team documents, search for that particular player and then update the player points (and the total points for that team). This is an [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/) operation.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I code it?

Comment: You might try using the [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#-position) positional update operator, or an update with a pipeline.

Comment: So, I was able to update the individual  player's points but now I am stuck on how to update the totalPoints of each team having that particular player.  Should I make an array and store the _id of each team (having this player) and then iterate through that array and increment the points into that or would you suggest any other way?